# Receptacle Troubleshooting

Tags: receptacle, troubleshooting

I have an outdoor receptacle that isn't working. I've checked for a tripped breaker, I've tried replacing the receptacle, and  I've confirmed that the breaker is getting power. Using a multimeter I've confirmed that the receptacle is not getting power. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: There could be a GFCI receptacle feeding that one that is tripped. Look around to see if you can find it.

Comment: What other receptacles are on the circuit?

Comment: OK - all of the indoor receptacles are working and there aren't any GFCI receptacles that are tripped. However, I just noticed that none of my outdoor receptacles are working.

Comment: I take it all your outdoor receptacles are on the same circuit then?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: If one of your outdoor receptacles is a GFCI unit (commonly the first in the chain from the panel), it might be faulty. I'd take it apart first. If all you have is regular receptacles, I'd start taking them apart (nearest the panel first) and checking connectivity.